# How to override/increase Java logging level for a package?

Tags: java, logging

I'd like to override the logging level for a specific package.

It works when the level is more restrictive, but it does not work when the level is less restrictive.

Here is an example:

```
public class Main {
  private static final java.util.logging.Logger JDK_LOGGER = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JDK_LOGGER.fine("Hello fine (jdk)...");
    JDK_LOGGER.info("Hello info (jdk)...");
    JDK_LOGGER.severe("Hello severe (jdk)...");
```

If the specified package has a more restrictive level, it works:

```
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
com.ice.level = SEVERE
```

It prints:

```
août 19, 2019 10:44:25 PM com.ice.foo.Main main
GRAVE: Hello severe (jdk)...
```

But if the specified package has a less restrictive level, it does not work as what I was expecting:

```
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level = INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
com.ice.level = FINE
```

It prints:

```
août 19, 2019 10:55:50 PM com.ice.foo.Main main
INFOS: Hello info (jdk)...
août 19, 2019 10:55:50 PM com.ice.foo.Main main
GRAVE: Hello severe (jdk)...
```

But, because FINE > INFO > SEVERE, I was expecting to see the 3 logs (fine, info and severe).

Where is my mistake?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is in not realizing that the package filter and the handler filter are applied independently, i.e. as-if they were AND'd.

The purpose of the `ConsoleHandler.level` filter is to *reduce* the console output, while allowing e.g. a file handler to log everything. It is mainly used when you are logging to both console and file at the same time.

As such, the handler level cannot be overridden.

The reason console output is usually filtered more than file output, is that console output is relatively expensive, performance-wise. You don't want large volume of output to the console, so finer-grained log messages are usually filtered out.

Comment: OK, therefore, how can I get a FINE level only for one specific package/class? I used to do that with log4j, especially for debuging.

Comment: @thierryler Your last example but with `ConsoleHandler.level = FINE` or no `ConsoleHandler.level`